# (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'WKBElement'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, geoserver, geoalchemy2

I am trying to send data from one database table to a separate database and table.
To do this I am working with sqlalchemy and geoalchemy2. Here is a snippet of the code.

```
s = sqlalchemy.select([source_table])
with engine.connect() as conn:
    rp = conn.execute(s)
    source_results = rp.fetchall()


#inserting Data
ins = target_table.insert()
with target_engine.connect() as conn:
    target_results = conn.execute(ins, source_results)
```

The error it returns is:

> ProgrammingError:(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type
>   'WKBElement'.

the column type is: Geometry(srid=4326)

Comment: can you check what you get back in the first query?

Comment: 'geometry' : <WKBElement at 0x2b0625574s8; 0101000020E6100000F800980CF24554C0A00CBFA773BE3A40>

Comment: I don't know if this is right but I converted this to a python string and it sent the data with no problems.